# Will this crystal-driven inverter successfully produce AC current?

Tags: inverter, crystal

[image]
The basic idea of this  is that the crystal X1 and filtering caps C1 and C2, will produce a simple square wave that feeds into the NPN transistor Q1. When Q1 is on, the input voltage that Q2 and Q4 are dependent on is 0, and is 12V when on the other side of the cycle. Q2 serves as a NOT gate for the FET Q3, thus inverting the current state of the FET Q4. This makes it so that as long as the circuit is on (has sufficient power), the FETs will always oppose each other and produce a sine wave.

My questions:

1. What are the current flaws in this design?
2. Will the crystal be able to handle the input of this transistor? I don't know how many watts are needed to drive a transistor, or how many can be supplied from a crystal.
3. What should the ideal values of R1 and R2 be? I was thinking anywhere between 25k and 75k would be sufficient.
4. Is there a way to tune this circuit so that I could find the resonating frequency of the transformer?
5. is there a maximum frequency that X1 can produce?

Comment: If Q3 and Q4 are FETs, then use FET symbols in your schematic.

Comment: @Dave Tweed  The FET symbol wasn't available,  strangely enough.  I figured that the wording and different symbols will do for now.  I'll be sure to fix it later.

Comment: Your oscillator won't oscillate - check out Pierce oscillator design

Comment: I based it off of this pierce oscillator https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PIERCE_CRYSTAL_OSCILLATOR.jpg#mw-jump-to-license

Comment: What frequency are you hoping for out of the transfomer? 50 Hz? 60 Hz or higher?

Comment: When you look at all the images of a pierce oscillator on google (https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=pierce+oscillator&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi8ro7o_anMAhVhIMAKHQ_uCc4QsAQIRQ&biw=1158&bih=922) why did you think that the simplest was most likely to work. No BJT biasing components is a big deal.

Comment: Please stop "slapping components together" and then asking "will this work" ? Because most of the time the answer will be **No**. The way most of us learned about design is to start by looking at **other people's designs** and trying to understand  **how they work**. **NO one** made a working design first time without having any knowledge from previous designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the current flaws in this design?

Here's a few thoughts: -

[image]

If you want to trial out designs that might work go and get a free download of LTSpice and start learning how to use a simulator.

For the rest of your questions, come back when you have at least something simulated that appears to work or has specific problems you can't narrow down.

Comment: I've had spice simulators bug out on me before,  but I'm willing to try.